# Win32 WinAPI EditBoX styles

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

How to create an EditBox using Win32 WinAPI so that it looks like the one you would get by placing an editBox in a VS designer in for example Visual C# or VB (with a nice top border etc.)? Here is an image of how it looks like and how it is when dropped in a designer:

[image]

I have tried this code:

```
hWndTextBox = CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"My default text",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL ,
        10,10,200,20,
        hWnd,
        (HMENU) ID_TEXTBOX,
        hInst,
        NULL);
```

But that one does not look like the box created in some .NET IDE designer. I have enabled visual styles in my Win32 application and I am using VS 2010 under Win7. I want it to look like the second one.

Comment: Which one do you want? The top one or the bottom one?

Comment: I want the bottom one. I must be missing some of the styles. I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I must be missing some of the styles. I hope

Yup, you must use CreateWindowEx() so you can specify WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE instead of WS_BORDER.  And use WM_SETFONT to set a decent TrueType font instead of the default Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

To create such effect you need to subclass the Editbox control and override the WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGND messages.

For info about subclassing see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx#subclassing_window

Comment: I would like to do it in one go via CreateWindow.

Comment: Your objetive was the first flat style or the second client_edge one?

Comment: Ok, I believed you wanted the flat one.